# IBM Watson connection not using server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ibm-watson

Are there any way we can connect IBM Watson assistant without using node.js
to run the server?

Can I connect it like Firebase?

Comment: WA is a REST API, so if you can call to it from your application, then your application can be hosted anywhere.

Comment: do you have any website linking to this API?

Comment: The related services documentation will have an API reference page. There are also different SDKs created. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud

Comment: I am creating a react application, how do I use WA in this case? I already have a  server, but it looks like all the example you provided need to create a second server which connecting to WA

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Watson Node SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk) to connect with the Watson Assistant API directly from your React application, without the need for another server. [This example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/examples/browserify/public/client.js) shows you how to connect a service in the context of a client-side application.

That example includes a server, just so that a user can run that example on their own. It is not required - you can import and instantiate the Watson Assistant SDK in your React code as long as `watson-developer-cloud` is installed in your project dependencies.

Other links you may find helpful:
- [Generic example for using Assistant](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk#assistant)
- [Documentation for the Watson Assistant API, including Node request examples](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl)